# Unity - Merge a texture/sprite (from camera) with a mask to create a new Sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, merge, sprite, texture2d

I'm trying to merge a picture taken with the phone with a sprite that would act like a mask. But, the user can rotate / scale the picture to fit the mask.
So I tried to use GetPixels() but it is useless as the picture can be scaled/rotated.

Here is a drawing to explain a bit what I'm trying to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfkYA.png

The result image should be the size of the mask, but filled with the picture content. Just like what we can have using a mask in a canvas, but as a sprite that can be used.